Challenges in fine-tuning OCR models with custom datasets
I've been experimenting with fine-tuning OCR models using a custom dataset, specifically with the doctr and PaddleOCR frameworks. My objective is to improve recognition accuracy, especially on documents that have undergone various alterations.
Here's my approach so far:

Created a custom dataset, applying noise (e.g., Gaussian noise, blur, salt and pepper) to around 60% of the images.
Fine-tuned both doctr and PaddleOCR models using this dataset.

However, instead of improvement, I observed a drop in accuracy compared to the original models. I expected that fine-tuning would enhance the ocr performance, but this hasn’t been the case.
Could there be an issue with my approach, or am I potentially overlooking some key aspect of fine-tuning?

Fine-tuning is tricky business. I have been trying to finetune spacy on custom data, and instead of getting better at the custom data its getting worse at other data.
Not apples to apples, just saying training from scratch could be better. Also I have never experienced good results with synthesized data.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
